# Mocking dynamic objects (constantize) rspec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4, rspec, mocking, rspec3

I'm using Rails 4.2, rspec 3 and ruby 2.1.2.

I want to stub/mock dynamic object, the original code to test is:

```
self.property_a.action_class_name.constantize.new.perform(payload)
```

How can i mock the result of that perform?

Thanks,

Shai.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for answering,

But i solved it in another way:

```
expect_any_instance_of(ModuleName::ClassName).to receive(:perform).and_return({a: 1})
```

Comment: That is an answer to a different question and probably a duplicate

Answer (score 3):

There are a lot of options depending on what you want to achieve. Here is one:

```
mock_class = Class.new do
  def perform(payload)
    :foo
  end
end

allow(<object>).to receive_message_chain(:property_a, :action_class_name, :constantize) { mock_class }
```